# Substitute (int) Math.round(x / 2.0)

Tags: java

Is is possible to substitute (int) Math.round(x / 2.0) with bitwise operations?

Comment: ......`x >> 1`?

Comment: What is the type of `x` and what is its range of possible values?

Comment: (int) Math.round (3 / 2) = 2 != 3 >> 1 = 1

Comment: integer x, x > 0

Comment: `Math.round()` with integers makes little sense; integer division always results in integers anyway.  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: `(x >> 1) + (x & 1)`

Comment: `(x+1)/2`. No bitwise operations required. Or `(x+1) >> 2`. Assuming `x >= 0` of course.

Comment: Works. Thx, Erwin.